Expectation of the product of two random variables
I recently tried to derive a formula that I saw in a paper. The scenario was a follows:
Let $X\in\lbrace 0,1\rbrace $ a.s. be a binary random variable and $Y$ be a continuous random variable. Let $a,b\in\mathbb{R}$. $X$ and $Y$ are correlated. For one part of the formula I had to compute $$\mathbb{E}[a^X\mathbb{I}(Y\geq t)b^{1-X}] $$
where $\mathbb{I}(Y\geq t)=1$, if $Y\geq t$ and $0$ otherwise.
As I am not 100% certain, I wonder if the following approach using conditional expectation is correct:
$$\mathbb{E}[a^X\mathbb{I}(Y\geq t)b^{1-X}]=\mathbb{E}\left[a^X\mathbb{I}(Y\geq t)b^{1-X}|X=0\right]\cdot\mathbb{P}(X=0)+\mathbb{E}\left[a^X\mathbb{I}(Y\geq t)b^{1-X}|X=1\right]\cdot\mathbb{P}(X=1) $$
$$=b\cdot\mathbb{P}(Y\geq t)\mathbb{P}(X=0)+a\mathbb{P}(Y\geq t)\mathbb{P}(X=1) $$

The conditional expectations needs to be conditional on the events $X=0$ and $X=1$, respectively.  Otherwise, if you condition on the random variables $I(X=0)$ and $I(X=1)$ as you do, the conditional expectation itself become a random variable which makes no sense here.  Also, is it true that $E(I(Y\ge t)|X=0)=P(Y\ge t)$ as you seem to assume?

You are right, the first part was a typo, which I fixed now. About the second part of your comment: I thought that $E[a^X I(Y\geq t)b^{1-X}|X=0]=E[a^0I(Y\geq t)b^{1-0}|X=0]=E[I(Y\geq t)b|X=0]=E[I(Y\geq t)b]$ holds in general. Is this not the case?

No, in general for an event $A$ you have $E(I(A))=P(A)$.  This also holds conditional on another event $B$, that is, $E(I(A)|B)=P(A|B)$.
